# Matching all elements from a list wth each entry of a input

Tags: python-3.x, performance, hash, regexp-replace

I have two text files. One is a list(key-value pairs) of items and the other is a input file that the key-value pairs are to be matched. If a match is found it is marked with its corresponding value in the input file.

**For example:**

**my list file:**

```
food = ###food123
food microbiology = ###food mircobiology456
mirco organism = ###micro organims789
geo tagging = ###geo tagging614
gross income = ###gross income630
fermentation = fermentation###929
contamination = contamination##878
Salmonella species = Salmonella species###786
Lactic acid bacteria = Lactic acid bacteria###654
```

**input file:**

```
There are certain attributes necessary for fermentation of meat. 
It should be fresh, with low level of contamination, the processing should be hygienic and the refrigeration should be resorted at different stages.
Elimination of pathogens like Coliform, Staphylococci, Salmonella species may be undertaken either by heat or by irradiation. There is need to lower the water activity and this can be achieved by either drying or addition of the salts. 
Inoculation with an effective, efficient inoculum consisting of Lactic acid bacteria and, or Micrococci which produces lactic acid and also contributes to the flavor development of the product. 
Effective controlled time, temperature humidity during the production is essential.
And, Salt ensures the low pH value and extends the shelf-life of the fermented meats like Sausages.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
There are certain attributes necessary for ((fermentation###929)) of meat. 
It should be fresh, with low level of ((contamination##878)), the processing should be hygienic and the refrigeration should be resorted at different stages.
Elimination of pathogens like Coliform, Staphylococci, ((Salmonella species###786)) may be undertaken either by heat or by irradiation. There is need to lower the water activity and this can be achieved by either drying or addition of the salts. 
Inoculation with an effective, efficient inoculum consisting of ((Lactic acid bacteria###654)) and, or Micrococci which produces lactic acid and also contributes to the flavor development of the product. 
Effective controlled time, temperature humidity during the production is essential.
And, Salt ensures the low pH value and extends the shelf-life of the fermented meats like Sausages.
```

For this I am using python3, parsing the list file, and storing it in a hash. Hash has all the elements of the list as key-value pairs. Then each line of input file is matched with all keys present in hash and when a match is found the corresponding hash value is replaced as shown in the output.

This method works fine when the size of input and list is small, but when both the list and input size grows its taking lot of time.

How can I improve the time complexity of this matching method?

**Algorithm I am using :**

```
#parse list and store in hash
for l in list:
  ll = l.split("=")
  hash[ll[0]] = ll[1]

#iterate input and match with each key
keys = hash.keys()
for line in lines:
    if(line != ""):
        for key in keys:
            my_regex = r"([,\"\'\( \/\-\|])" + key + r"([ ,\.!\"।\'\/\-)])"
            if((re.search(my_regex, line, re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE))):
                 line = re.sub(my_regex, r"\1" + "((" + hash[key] + "))" + r"\2",line)
```

Comment: What with "food microbiology" vs "food" in the input file?

Comment: both are in list file. Preference is for food microbiology in input if its not there food will be given preference.@Danny_ds